# What is wrong with my Jquery code? Trying to not reload form if passwords dont match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, flask

I am trying to get my form not to reload if my password 1 and 2 dont match when I click submit. What is wrong with my code, attaching html and js.

```
<label for="password">Lösenord: </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Lösenord" required>
        <p>
        </p>
        <label for="password2">Upprepa Lösenord: </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Lösenord" required>
        <p>
        </p>
```

```
$(document).ready( function() {

  $("#submit").click( function() {
    var password1 = $("#password");
    var password2 = $("#password2");
    alert(password2);
    if (password1 /= password2) {
      preventDefault();
    }

  });
});
```

UPDATE: Tried changing to "!=" and passwor.val(), still does not work..

Comment: ignore the "alert function"

Comment: `password1 /= password2` ? what are you trying with division  here ?

Comment: I think you have a typo, "password1 /= password2"  should beif password1 != password2

Comment: @CodeManiac I'm pretty sure they're attempting "not =" there. I think Haskell uses that operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the issues pointed out by @Joshua Robles,

Add an empty `value` attribute to your input fields like this:

`<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Lösenord" value="" required>`

Full code and demo:

```js
 $("#submit").click( function(event) {
    var password1 = $("#password").val();
    var password2 = $("#password2").val();

    if (password1 !== password2) {
      alert("Passwords don't match")
      event.preventDefault();
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="password">Lösenord: </label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Lösenord" value="" required>
<p></p>
<label for="password2">Upprepa Lösenord: </label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Lösenord" value="" required>
<p></p>
<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, you are only getting the reference to the DOM element. To get the value, you need to use `.val()`

You are also doing a division instead of a comparison. Your if statement comparison should be:

`if (password1.val() !== password2.val()) {`

You also need to pass the event object on your click listener. So overall, it should be:

```
  $("#submit").click( function(event) {
    var password1 = $("#password").val();
    var password2 = $("#password2").val();

    if (password1 !== password2) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

  });
```

Comment: Tried that, saw my typo, still doesn't work. Should I change my var declarations aswell or should they remain the same?

Comment: Yeah didn't notice. Is there an exposed global `preventDefault` function on your code? You might need to have an `event` param on your onClick function and use the `preventDefault` function from that object. I'll update my answer

Comment: I dont have an onclick function for the submit button, it works via my routes.py and sends a post method. Im thinking that Jquery dominates that? I'm new in jquery. My thought was that preventDefault prevents the post method that submit generally does.

Comment: You are creating a click event listener on your submit button. I suggest you read up on javascript basics and how jquery works in order to fully understand what you're trying to do. Then again, I don't suggest you use jQuery since a lot of functions they used to provide are now already available on modern browsers. I updated my answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

A part of attaching the click event to `preventDefault()`, 
The simple logic comparator `!=` should be used in your example since it is agnostic to the object type, finally prevent true validation if fields are empty

```js
  $("#submit").click( function(event) {
    var password1 = $("#password").val().length>0 ? $("#password").val() : 'a';
    var password2 = $("#password2").val().length>0 ? $("#password2").val() : 'b';
     //prevent true if empty
    if (password1 != password2) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="">
<label for="password">Lösenord: </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Lösenord" required>
        <p>
        </p>
        <label for="password2">Upprepa Lösenord: </label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Lösenord" required>
        <p>
        <button id="submit">Ok</button>
        </p>
 </form>
```